# Updating "anyarray" or "anyelement" polymorphic functions when upgrading to 14.x or higher on AWS RDS aurora postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aggregate-functions, postgresql-14

When upgrading AWS RDS aurora postgresql cluster from 11.17 -> 15.2, I was met with this fatal error in the pg_upgrade logs:

```
fatal
Your installation contains user-defined objects that refer to internal
polymorphic functions with arguments of type "anyarray" or "anyelement".
These user-defined objects must be dropped before upgrading and restored
afterwards, changing them to refer to the new corresponding functions with
arguments of type "anycompatiblearray" and "anycompatible".
```

AWS does not mention this in the upgrade docs, so I thought the changed may have been introduced by a system user. After a bit of digging, it seems that the aggregate functions changed the way the types are named (in postgresql version 14 to be clear). So how do I update this?

I ran a subset the query that the upgrade failed on, on each DB in the target cluster:

```
--find incompatibilites on each DB:
\c <DATABASE>

SELECT 'aggregate' AS objkind,
       p.oid::regprocedure::text AS objname
FROM pg_proc AS p
JOIN pg_aggregate AS a ON a.aggfnoid=p.oid
JOIN pg_proc AS transfn ON transfn.oid=a.aggtransfn
WHERE p.oid >= 16384
  AND a.aggtransfn = ANY(ARRAY['array_append(anyarray,anyelement)', 'array_cat(anyarray,anyarray)', 'array_prepend(anyelement,anyarray)', 'array_remove(anyarray,anyelement)', 'array_replace(anyarray,anyelement,anyelement)', 'array_position(anyarray,anyelement)', 'array_position(anyarray,anyelement,integer)', 'array_positions(anyarray,anyelement)', 'width_bucket(anyelement,anyarray)']::regprocedure[]);

  objkind  |         objname         
-----------+-------------------------
 aggregate | array_accum(anyelement)
(1 row)
```

Okay, so now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
--drop aggregate from sub 14.x db
mygreatdatabase=> DROP AGGREGATE array_accum(anyelement);
DROP AGGREGATE

--upgrade to 14.x or higher, and then re-create using updated type:
mygreatdatabase=> CREATE AGGREGATE array_accum(anycompatible) (SFUNC = array_append,STYPE = anycompatiblearray,INITCOND = '{}');
```

My hope is that AWS adds this to the documentation on RDS Aurora PostgresQL Upgrade Pre-Checks, but this will be here until that is more clear.

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading from postgresql 13.x to 14.x on MacOS using homebrew.  This did the trick.  Thanks, @Mike!

Comment: Are you supposed to do that change before upgrade, in Postgres 13?

Comment: @Roman, yes. Drop aggregate in sub 14. Then do the upgrade, and finally recreate. See the solution comments.

Comment: In my case I just needed to drop and recreate the `pg_repack` extension on the affected databases.